# How do I allocate memory for dynamic array of structures in a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I have the below structure and I am trying to allocate the space for the structure Zone below.

At present, I am allocating the space for the zone as:

```
zone *zones = (zone*)malloc(sizeof(zone) + (sizeof(school)*3));
```

Assume, I have 3 schools and 3 competitions inside each school

```
typedef struct competition { 
    int prize_1;
    int prize_2;
    int prize_3;
} competition;

typedef struct school {
        int school_id;
    competition *competitions;//[Singing, Dancing, Soccer....]
    
} school;

typedef struct zone {
    school *schools; //[School 0, School 1, School 2.....];
} zone;
```

When I try to access:

```
school *cs = &(zones->school[0]); //Get the appropriate school
int schoolId = cs->school_id; //get the school id of a school
```

I get a segmentation fault error. I know I am not allocating the memory properly for the Zone but i am not sure on how to allocate the memory properly

Answer (score 1):

The `schools` member isn't pointing anywhere, so attempting to dereference that pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to first allocate space for the zone, then for the array of schools it points to:

```
zone *zones = malloc(sizeof(zone));
zones->schools = malloc(sizeof(school)*3);
```

Comment: So should I be allocating separate space for the "competitions" in individual school? or can I allocate the space for all the competitions in all the schools at once? Can you please help me in the same and that would be really helpful?

Comment: @weijong Yes, you also need to allocate the space that each `competitions` member points to.

Comment: Here I have 3 schools, so should I go into each school and allocate the space indivdiually for each school for each competition? For say, I have 100 schools, it would be difficult for me to get into each school and create a space for competitions in each school right? Any suggestions are appreciated please!

Comment: @weijong Yes, you need to allocate space that each `competitions` member points to.

Comment: @weijong Not difficult, you just need a loop.

Comment: 1. I would check if the allocation did not  fail. 2. I would use objects instead of types in `sizeof`

Answer (score 1):

To use your allocation arithmetic, you need to use flexible array members instead of pointers when possible as it simplifies allocation and deallocation.

- Remember to store the number of allocated objects too.
- Always check for allocation errors and provide error handling.

```
typedef struct competition { 
    int prize_1;
    int prize_2;
    int prize_3;
} competition;

typedef struct school 
{
    int school_id;
    size_t numCompetitions;
    competition competitions[];
    
} school;

typedef struct zone 
{
    size_t numSchools;
    school *schools[];
} zone;

school *allocateSchool(size_t numCompetitions)
{
    school *sch = malloc(sizeof(*sch) + numCompetitions * sizeof(sch -> competitions[0]));
    if(sch) sch -> numCompetitions = numCompetitions;
    return sch;
}

zone *allocateZones(size_t numZones)
{
    zone *zn = malloc(sizeof(*zn) + numZones * sizeof(zn -> schools[0]));
    if(zn) zn -> numSchools = numZones;
    return zn;
}
```

Comment: OT: To me the name `numZones` is confusing. I would prefer `numSchools`